# How to write a dataframe in pyspark having null values to CSV

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using the below code to write to a CSV file.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("nullValue"," ").save("/home/user/test_table/")
```

when I execute it, I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support null data type.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Could you please update question attaching `df.printSchema()` result?

Comment: how are your null values stored? When I used Python's `None` type as null object and did a save, it worked fine. 

`df  = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  (1.0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
  (1.0, "Spark is awesome"),
  (0.0, None),
  (0.0, "And I don't know why...")
], ["label", "sentence"])
    
df.printSchema() 

df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .option("nullValue"," ").save(drive+"/test.csv")`

Comment: Were you able to find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (not using that command with the `nullValue` option) and I solved it by using the `fillna` method.

And I also realised that fillna was not working with `_corrupt_record`, so I dropped since I didn't need it.

```py
df = df.drop('_corrupt_record')
df = df.fillna("")
df.write.option('header', 'true').format('csv').save('file_csv')
```